# RSS notification in System tray

Tags: windows, rss, notifications

I am looking for a tiny windows app that will sit in my system tray and check certain RSS feeds periodically, upon new RSS update the items should be displayed as pop-up (or balloons).

There are quite a few full-features RSS readers out there that do that, but I am only looking for this notification feature and would like to spend as little resources as possible for it.

Comment: If I do this, my productivity goes from 25% to like 4%

Comment: Try to setup alert for your freelancing job ;)

Comment: If you're currently using Windows 10, please refer to my answer at: http://superuser.com/a/978664/323140

Answer (score 31):

I wrote an application that does exactly what you asked for.

http://www.feednotifier.com/

Comment: Seems to work great, nice job! Perfect for monitoring my superuser questions!

Comment: @FogleBird if you could add the ability to stack the feeds much like Alertbear does, this would be the ideal RSS notifier app.

Comment: It would be great if it could integrate google reader! :)

Comment: I really like the feednotifier, but I have experienced some problems with it not displaying the right items from my feed. But other readers does.

Comment: Perfect little app!

Comment: FeedNotifier: got stuck after downloading some feed and never updated anything again (after uninstall and re-install again it breaks the same way).

Comment: I second to @yoshkemu , it works beautifully until it stop to receive feed.

Comment: FeedNotifier is abandoned and doesn't connect to servers using just TLS 1.1 up.

Comment: Site is down as of 2020-01-15. Exe can be downloaded on archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20191024010601/https://www.feednotifier.com/

Answer (score 5):

Way back when, I used [Abilon](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/win/34462), which popped up every 10 minutes(I think) doing exactly as you describe. I stopped using it when I noticed my productivity dropping through the floor.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a list I made, when I checked out different notifiers for my private rss feed:

- [Sharpreader](http://www.sharpreader.net/): Download 1MB, In memory 42MB (popup tested & works)
- [Feed notifier](https://www.feednotifier.com/download/): Download 7MB, In memory 35MB. (popup tested & works)
- Google Reader Notifier: Download 1MB, In memory 24MB. (does not support private rss feeds)
- Fuzzyduck: Download 4MB, In memory 14MB (does not support private rss feeds)
- Abilon: Download 1MB, In memory 13MB
- Klipfolio: Download 2MB, In memory 7MB (does not support private rss feeds, popup tested & works)
- Rssnotifier seems to be dead.
- Enigma Desktop seems a bit overkill.

Please give updates to this list in the comments

Comment: need to include links to the software, @jous.

Comment: @studiohack I noticed they're all applications mentioned in the previous answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Reader Notifier for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-notifier-windows/) is the standalone version for Google Reader. You do not need Firefox for this and it sits in the system tray.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Feed Notifier](http://feednotifier.com).

It's light, simple, and it support RSS feeds with authentication, like Basecamp feeds...

Answer (score 0):

[Google Reader Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3977) as a firefox plugin

I know it is not a windows app but it is the smallest... [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/) can be a good option but full feature tool.

Comment: I use Chrome though, not firefox :(

Comment: Just a heads-up: Google Reader Notifier is packed with ad/spyware: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3977#reviews

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Klipfolio](http://downloads.klipfolio.com/downloads/klipfolio-personal-dashboard) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the [Engima Desktop](http://kaelri.deviantart.com/art/Enigma-103823591) is an RSS reader overlay on your desktop.  This way you can have a persistent view of your feeds, even if you miss the balloon pop-up.