# Feed notification icon in tray — icon, not baloon or popup

Tags: rss, notifications, notification-area, feed, atom-feed

I'm searching for a feed reader:

- Windows
- No new items → default icon
- New items → special icon
- Can access password-protected websites

I don't want to be interrupted, I just want to see in a moment if there are new revisions in the repository. Something like [Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/), but with changing icons.

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/9929/rss-notification-in-system-tray

Answer (score 0):

There are two notification protocols/programs which may have plugins, programs or extensions which will serve your purposes. Both of these provide non-intrusive configurable pop up messages.

[Snarl](http://www.fullphat.net/index.php)

[Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx)

Apologies if Windows suggestions aren't appropriate, I've assumed that you are looking for Windows tools.

Answer (score 0):

See if 'Snarfer' or 'RSS Bandit' serves the purpose. These work for RSS and also look similar to Outlook. Both these apps are meant for Windows.